# How do I export all the Python docs of a package and get it into Devhelp?

Tags: programming, python, documentation

At the moment, to read the documentation of a package, `quickly` for examle, I do this:

```
>>> import quickly
>>> help(quickly)
 
>>> import quickly.widgets
>>> help(quickly.widgets)
 
>>> import quickly.widgets.text_editor
>>> help(quickly.widgets.text_editor)
```

and so on...

This is obviously very tedious. How can I export all of the quickly documentation, including all sub-packages, then get it to show up in the `devhelp` documentation browser?

Exporting the documentation as HTML would be nice too. I would even be happy if some version of it existed on the web, but I can't seem to find one.

Note: By *package* I mean a [[image] python-package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages), not a .deb package.

Comment: I think Devhelp uses some kind of structured HTML or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create HTML documentation of a python module using [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net) [image: Install epydoc].

> Epydoc is a tool for generating API documentation for Python modules, based on their docstrings.

Here is how to use `epydoc` to create HTML documentation for the module `quickly.widgets`:

```
epydoc --html quickly.widgets -o quickly_widgets_doc
```

Once this finishes, open up `quickly_widgets_doc/index.html` in your web browser:

[image]

Or, if you would prefer this documentation in a PDF:

```
epydoc --pdf quickly.widgets --name "quickly.widgets" -o quickly_widgets_doc_pdf
```

This creates the file `quickly_widgets_doc_pdf/api.pdf`

[image]

More information on using `epydoc` [here](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-reference.html).

I haven't found a way to convert these to a format DevHelp can use, if I do I'll edit this answer.

Answer (score 5):

I little known "secret" is the [pydoc tool](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) that is included with every Python installation (so no need to install extra packages).

Start a webserver that generates instant documentation from the source (using the same techniques as `help()` in the Python console) that listens on http://localhost:8000/ with:

```
pydoc -p 8000
```

Launch the webserver and a Tkinter-based GUI that provides search options etc.:

```
pydoc -g
```

Write the documentation for quickly.widgets to a HTML file quickly.widgets.html in the current directory:

```
pydoc -w quickly.widgets
```

Comment: Brilliant! Although I only got this to work right after running `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python` - just in case anybody has a similar problem.

Comment: That sounds like you have installed python or python modules outside the default Ubuntu packages?

Comment: BTW: the Ubuntu packages also provide `pydoc2.6`, `pydoc2.5`, etc., which I assume will show documentation for the respective Python versions...